# Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control... even using CreateControl()

Tags: c#, invoke

Im not able to modify from my Form1 an element that belongs to Form 2.

```
public partial class Project : Form
{
    public Form2 form = new Form2();

    public Project()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Project_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.CreateControl();
    }

    private void buttonOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.Show();
    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var indata = *whatever serial input data here*
        bool result = Int32.TryParse(indata, out int data);

        if (result) {
        form.chart1.Invoke(new Action(() => { form.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(data); }));
        }
    }
```

Any time I press my button in order to show Form2 and its chart, an exception is raised in `form.chart1.Invoke`: `Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.`

Why is this happening if i'm forcing `form` to do a `CreateControl()` ?

Comment: Windows Forms uses Windows User32, Gdi32 and other traditional Windows libraries under the covers.  When you instantiate a Form object, you create a hollow wrapper for a Windows window.  When you Show the form, a complicated dance begins that at one point calls the traditional Windows `Create` function to create the window (and the window handle to the window).  Until that time, there are certain things you can't do.  So, until the time that your Form2 is completely finished creating itself (it's definitely finished by the `Form.Load` event), you can't `Invoke` anything on the form

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you what is wrong.

Your serial port is firing before the `form2` (that holds your chart) is fully created

I guess you could check the visible flag (there are probably many others)

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

   ...

   if(!form?.Visible)
      return;

   form.chart1.Invoke(...
```

*The assumption is if its not visible, you don't want to display the data*

---

**Further reading**

[Order of Events in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms)

> **Application Startup and Shutdown Events**
>
> The Form and Control classes expose a set of events related to
>   application startup and shutdown. When a Windows Forms application
>   starts, the startup events of the main form are raised in the
>   following order:
>
> Control.HandleCreated
>
> Control.BindingContextChanged
>
> Form.Load
>
> Control.VisibleChanged
>
> Form.Activated
>
> Form.Shown